# Cannot use a Component declared in a "CoreModule" but can use services

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components, angular-module

I am trying to follow the angular docs so that I only have one instance of a specific module. Specifically the [CoreModule](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#the-core-module) and the [SharedModule](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#shared-modules) sections.

The demo at the bottom of the links above works for only importing `CoreModule` once in the AppModule, where the lazy loaded `HeroesModule` and `HeroComponent` can reference the `UserService` declared in the `CoreModule`

My problem comes in when trying to use a Component that has been declared and exported from a "CoreModule".

For example the default `HeroComponent` works like:

```
// Exact copy except import UserService from core
import { Component }   from '@angular/core';

import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
import { UserService } from '../core/user.service';

@Component({
  template: `
    <h2>Heroes of {{userName}}</h2>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  providers: [ HeroService ]
})
export class HeroComponent {
  userName = '';
  constructor(userService: UserService) {
    this.userName = userService.userName;
  }
}
```

but if I modify it to include the `app-title` component declared in the `CoreModule` it breaks with the error `'app-title' is not a known element`

```
// Exact copy except import UserService from core
import { Component }   from '@angular/core';

import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
import { UserService } from '../core/user.service';

@Component({
  template: `
    <h2>Heroes of {{userName}}</h2>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-title></app-title>
  `,
  providers: [ HeroService ]
})
export class HeroComponent {
  userName = '';
  constructor(userService: UserService) {
    this.userName = userService.userName;
  }
}
```

I have copied the example from the angular.io docs below, and have only modified the `app/hero/hero.component.ts` template to include `<app-title></app-title>`,

Example: click the "Heroes"  button after the app loads

https://plnkr.co/edit/SZOEvdRCT23S4DfbGmut?p=preview

edit: second example, click "Contact" after the app loads

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ym6ya?file=contact/contact.component.html

Any suggestions on getting the components from `CoreModule` to work in lazy loaded modules, or information on why I shouldn't expect this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: there are no errors in the plunker you provided....

Comment: @Claies my apoligies, I should have specified, please click the "Heroes" button

Comment: It's really easy to create an Angular reproduction with http://stackblitz.com. The Heroes plunker is a mess because it contains way too much code.

Comment: Seems to work fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebbmhl

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the problem only seems to affect lazy loaded modules, there aren't any in your example

Comment: You could try to reproduce using my stackblitz. Try to reproduce with as little code as possible https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer [updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ym6ya?file=contact/contact.component.html)  , after it loads, click "Contact"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use components, directives, or pipes from a module, you need to add the module that provides them to `imports: [...]`, to **every** module where they are used.

Services are hoisted in the application root scope, if provided or imported by the AppModule, or in the root scope of the lazy loaded module that imports them (lazy loaded modules introduces a child scope to the application root scope), and therefore only need to be imported once.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ds2rce?file=core%2Fcore.module.ts

Comment: so it's not possible to prevent component, directives, and pipes from being shared between modules? Also, do you have a reference to the angular docs where this is mentioned?

Comment: There are lots of module docs. I don't remember where the things are mentioned. I don't really understand what you mean ba preventing components, directives, and pipes to be shared. Why would you want that?

Comment: I have a few components that are shared between lazy loaded components. I don't want to create a new instance of the shared module and all their components for every lazy loaded module.

Comment: An instance of a lazy loafed module is only a DI child scope. Component instances are only created when used in another components template. There is no cost involved worth mentioning.